# Can I increase the frequency at which location history gets my location?

Tags: google, google-maps, geolocation, google-location-history

I've recently discovered Google Location History, however my history map is made up of lots of very long straight lines because it doesn't appear to get checkpoint/location information very often.

Is there any way to increase how many times it gets the location in order to get a more accurate view of my movements in a day? I understand that this may reduce battery life.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using some [tracking app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking)? Some of them allow you to define intervals. If you insist all those data should be going to the cloud, so Google can profile you: I don't know for sure, but I would expect them to pick that up if it's available.

Answer (score 2):

"Start driving"[1] in Google Maps increases the frequency to 15 seconds per sample. Then send it to background, turn off the screen. It consumes more battery but not much.

[1] since the side menu has been removed, the feature can only be used by adding a shortcut (sometimes called widget) to your home screen.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I've noted that Google Maps increases the frequency with which it captures location data if I'm using another device that intensively uses the phone's GPS, such as a Bluetooth-connected activity and fitness tracker. When it is active it seems to induce Google Maps to collect the same data with the same frequency as the fitness tracker.