# How to see my location log in the Google Maps without a working network connection?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to see my google maps position log even if I was offline, or I did not use my phone.

My impression is that the position logging works only if either the phone is active or if I am on wifi.

I would like if I would see my position log more often. I think, the best would be if some background task would continuously (or, maybe in every 10 minutes or so) log my position data, save it, and upload to the google maps if I am online.

Is it possible somehow? It is not a problem, if it would require some other map application, although the gmaps would be ideal.

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/152077/50837) works only if I manually turn it on every time. I do not want to do that, I need an automatic solution.